# What is the recommended method for handling tables that can have unlimited columns?

Tags: sql-server, database, schema

I am working on a creating a database schema that reflects a relationship where an assembly part can under-go multiple different stages with multiple different pricings attached to each record. I looked into the EAV data structure and was wondering if there are any other ways to handle this type of situation.

Example: An assembly part for a machine will need to have various costs attached to it before it actually becomes a machine. There can be 50+ different price stages such as setup charge, paint, labor, etc. for each part. Additionally, each one of those parts can become another part in order to become a machine which will have it's own unique pricing criteria and database record.

I looked into both recursion and the EAV data structure but as I'm creating the schema it seems like this can get messy really quick.

Comment: Are you sure SQL Server is the best place for this data? JSON functionality is getting better and better with each new version, so you could manage ragged data by just storing some of it as JSON documents, but other products might be more mature in this area.

Comment: (I don't really understand your data model or have any way to judge what is "messy" or "quick" for you, but another possibility is [SQL Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-architecture?view=sql-server-ver16).)

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker I have to use SQL Server, I have thought about using a JSON based data and have used it for other personal projects. Also, The way I am judging whether something is messy is by how complex these queries will be for the next person who needs to utilize the database or normalization issues.

Comment: Why does this scenario suggest having lots of columns instead of just having multiple rows, eg `assembly_cost(assembli_id, id, cost_type, cost_date, amount, ...)`?

Comment: @Hunterror But still, messy, quick, complex, these are all _subjective_ constructs. Messy for you might be very tidy for me, complex for me might be very simple for you.